# Delete records using integer list

Tags: salesforce

I want to Loop through the array of integers and want to remove the items in the TLToProcess list which i have stored in the array of integers

here is the code 
I want to remove only the selected in the list  integer

iSize.add(TLToProcess.size());

```
        if(TLToProcess[i].Scan_In1__c==null)
        {   
            if(TLToProcess[i].typew__c=='Pending')
            {
            TLForMissingHHhh.add(TLToProcess[i]);
            }
        }
         else if ( c[i].Scan_In1__c!=null)
        {
            if (TLToProcess[i].typew__c=='Pending' )
            {
            TLToProcess[i].typew__c='Processed';

            }
        }
        }
```

Now i want to remove record  1 by 1 from TLToProcess using 
remove() can any body tell me how to do it.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your problem, but if what you're trying to avoid is modifying your List of integers inside a loop and getting this error: {"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."} you can create a copy of your List(.ToList()) and use it to iterate, and this way you can call Remove() safely.

```
    List<Int32> arr = new List<Int32>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr.Add(i);
    }
    foreach(var o in arr.ToList())
    {
        arr.Remove(o);
    }
```

Is that the intent?